# Index was outside the bounds of the array while copying value in a string array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

When I run the code, it says that "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
string xyz ="";abc: 123 ;234 ;345 ;def: 234 ;456 ;xyz: 123;"";
string[] lines1 = abc.Split(':');
string[] buffer1 = new string[]{};
for (int i = 0; i < lines1.Length; i++)
{
    //string[] lines2 = lines1[i].Split(';');
    string[] lines2 = lines1[i].Split(new char[] { ';' },
                                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int j = 0; j < lines2.Length; j++)
    {
        buffer1[j] = lines2[j];
    }                
}
```

In the `buffer1[j] = lines2[j]`, I am copying the value of each `lines2` in `buffer1` which I need to use after the second loop. But I am getting that exception in that line when I run the code.

Comment: The declaration of buffer1 is not included. buffer1 could be an array of length 1 for all we know. The second you try to do buffer[2], you would get this error. check out your declaration

Comment: and there's your problem. buffer1 is an array of length 0. You cannot just add onto it and assume the size will change dynamically. You should try using a list instead, it is like an arraylist but better.

Comment: If i want to use array instead of list/arraylist. How should I declare my array then?

Comment: why do you want to use an array instead of a list? there are not going to be any nice solutions with arrays instead of lists.

Comment: because the values that I am getting in lines2, I want to put those values in an excel sheet in some specific way.. for which i need to do a looping.. so I need the array.

Comment: you can use a foreach loop instead of a for loop in order to access all the values in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer1` is an array, which means that it's of a fixed sized and can't grow to hold what you're trying to put in it. If you try to access `buffer1[16]` and `buffer1` isn't large enough for that, it will throw the exception you're seeing.

Instead of an array, try using a `List<int>`:

```
var buffer1 = new List<int>();
foreach (string item in lines1)
{
    buffer1.AddRange(item.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

This will allow you to add as many items to buffer1 as you want.

Comment: If i want to use array instead of list/arraylist. How should I declare my array then?

Comment: You'd need to figure out how many items will need to go into the array and then declare it with the proper size before actually inserting them.

Comment: Why would you want to use an array instead of a list?